# Hash Table - Why do we hash the keys instead of just using the input as the key?

Tags: javascript, data-structures, hashtable

I'm learning about hash tables, but can't understand why we hash the keys. Since our hashing functions are idempotent, what's the point? Why not just use the input to the hashing function to use in our lookups?

I only know javascript, so maybe that has something to do with why I don't fully understand it.

Comment: How do you propose to use a string to look up in an array?

Comment: I think this comment helps the most. It's because we're using numerical keys to lookup values in an array? Why an array instead of just an object? I'm coming from a javascript understanding. Is data usually stored sequentially in an array-like structure?

Comment: How would you implement that? Javascript objects are (typically) themselves implemented as hash tables.

Comment: Under the hood, everything is just bytes in RAM at specific (numeric) addresses.

Comment: Got it, makes sense now. So we're hashing keys to numeric addresses. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Because it's faster. Using the input itself would be a much more expensive computation depending on the values involved. As it's a generic algorithm that has to deal with many types os values it's much better to use a value than the string itself.

Comment: So the main reason is so that our keys are normalized? Makes sense to me!

Answer (score 0):

You said:

> Since each unique input to the hashing function results in the same, unique output, what's the point?

That statement is demonstrably false.

For example, if your keys are 16-character strings and you're creating a 32-bit hash code, then by the [Pigeonhole Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle), you will have collisions.

There are 2^32 (4 billion and change) possible 32-bit integers. Even if your 16-character strings are limited to the 26 alphabetic characters, and the digits 0-9, you have 36^16 (7.95 e24) possible strings. So, on average, there are 1,853,020,188,851,841 strings for every possible hash code.

That's why hash tables have to implement a collision resolution policy. It's also why selection of a good hash function is important: you want to even those collisions out as much as possible.

Comment: I misspoke when I said unique output, I meant to say that for each input, the output hash should always be the same. I'm aware that collisions happen, but they're not what confuses me.

Comment: @icey-t I suggest you edit your question and correct that statement.